# Conditional statements on CheckBox & TextBox in Userforms (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am new to coding UserForms  in VBA and require a bit of assistance with coding a conditional statement on a certain number of pairs of CheckBoxs and TextBoxs. 
        Clearly a loop will be involved, but I just cant seem to incorporate it. Here is one of the methods I have tried and failed with:

```
    For i = 1 To 12
    If CheckBox(i).Value = True And TextBox(i) = "" Or CheckBox(i).Value = False And TextBox(i).Value <> "" Then
    MsgBox ("Warning")
End If
Next i
```

Thank you for any help!!!!!!
Regards

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I trying to achieve a situation where the first 12 pairs of Checkbox and TextBox  are fully ticked (in the Checkbox case) and filled (in the textbox case). If this is not the case, then a warning message appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `UserForm` are not CheckBox or TextBox collections. Thats why `CheckBox(index)` or `TextBox(index)` will not work.

But there is a `Controls` collection.

```
 For i = 1 To 12
  'If CheckBox(i).Value = True And TextBox(i) = "" Or CheckBox(i).Value = False And TextBox(i).Value <> "" Then

  If Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True And Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = "" _
    Or Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = False And Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value <> "" Then
   MsgBox ("Warning")
  End If
 Next
```

Assuming all `CheckBox`es have corresponding `TextBox`es with same numbers, `CeckBox1` - `TextBox1`, `CeckBox2` - `TextBox2`, ... then:

```
 Dim oControl As Control
 Dim sTextBoxName As String
 For Each oControl In Me.Controls
  If LCase(TypeName(oControl)) = "checkbox" Then
   sTextBoxName = Replace(oControl.Name, "checkbox", "textbox", , , vbTextCompare)
   If oControl.Value = (Me.Controls(sTextBoxName).Value = "") Then
    MsgBox "Warning " & Me.Controls(sTextBoxName).Name & ", " & oControl.Name
   End If
  End If
 Next
```

Comment: Just a small hint: `If Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = (Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = "") Then` will do the same ;)

Comment: Out of interest, how could we extend this all check boxes? So n would not be stated. would we stat with some kind of:  For Each ctl In Me.Controls    statement ?

Comment: When I say n, I mean the n in,  For i=1 To n.

Comment: See my supplement.